# Unresolved reference with Modifier methods in Jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm learning Jetpack Compose and I was trying to customize a display of an image with Modifier methods height and padding. But I got the Problem messages "Unresolved reference: height" and "Unresolved reference: padding".

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun imageDisplay() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
    ) {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(R.drawable.photo_1505740420928_5e560c06d30e),
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(180.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp)),
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop

        )

    }

}
```

[padding and height methods highlighted in red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dl7we.png)

Am I missing something?

Comment: The code should work. Are you using compose 1.0.0-beta05 ?

Comment: I'm using compose 1.0.0-beta01.

Comment: This happened to me when I accidentally imported `import java.lang.reflect.Modifier` instead of `import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier`.

Answer (score 22):

Make sure that the package import is correct. Sometimes we accidently import the wrong package for the `Modifier` function

Use the correct package.

```
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
```

Comment: Thanks! I had inadvertently used import java.lang.reflect.Modifier

Answer (score 11):

Everything looks fine. Make sure you're using the newest version of Android Studio, gradle and compose versions.

- Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Canary 5
- Compose Version 1.2.0-alpha05

```
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
implementation "androidx.compose.material:material-ripple:$compose_version"
```

And finally, check if you imported the correct `Modifier` class.
You must use the one from `androidx.compose.ui` package.

Comment: Mine was from `java.lang.Reflect`: that must be the cause.

Comment: The `finally` clause in this answer was my issue.  Thanks Nelson!  I had same - incorrect Modifier class from `Reflect` package

Answer (score 2):

Updating your Compose and Kotlin plugin version in the project level gradle files would fix it. If that does not work then try syncing project with gradle files.

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping my Column composable in a Row composable made modifier = Modifier.weight(1f) work.

Answer (score -2):

Problem is resolve :-
Import this ---

import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier

Comment: You shouldn't add copied answer as your answer. Its basically copy of above provided answer